# Issue with SMS integration; Error Code:E612

Tags: php, sms

I tried the below code for SMS integration in my website, but returns error: "Invalid Template Match".
How can I solve this?

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('sms.kappian.com/api/v3/index.php?method=sms&api_key=APIKEYGOESHERE&to=NUMBERHERE&sender=USER&message=testing&format=json&custom=1,2&flash=0') , true);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: contact with your sms gateway provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a. I think you must approve appropriate templates from your sms gateway provider, before you sent it.
b. check every word and spell with approved template, if you already approved a sms template,